# How to put 'all' condition inside of linq joins.(Sql query prepared)

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, entity-framework-core

I am working with Entity Framework Core 2   and Postgresql

I am trying to accept all data when my field is null like pasted sql db query;

```
select  
    "All"."Market",
    alarms."CPersentage",
from "All
left JOIN "Alarms" as alarms 
on "All"."Market" = coalesce(alarms."Buy", "All"."Market") //if alarms."Buy" = null then equaility became true!
```

But i couldn't prepare this conditional equalization on "ef core" İ have tryed this;

```
var result =(from firstALL in Db.All
            join alarm in Db.Alarms on
            new
            {
                BUY = firstALL.Market,
                Parity = firstALL.Parity
            } equals new
            {
                BUY = alarm.Buy?? firstALL.Market,    //Problem is here: The name 'firstALL' is not in scope on the right side of 'equals'
                Parity = alarm.Parity?? firstALL.Parity
            }
            into alarmg
            from alarmgi in alarmg.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new
            {
                BUY = firstALL.Market,
                CPersentage = alarmgi.CPersentage
            });
```

Summery : I am trying make equality true when left joined parameters are null , null.

But error is : The name 'firstALL' is not in scope on the right side of 'equals'

Comment: Your ** in your first query makes it surprisingly hard to read.

Comment: Rather than think in terms of coalesce, think in terms of your comment. You want to check whether `alarm?.Buy` is `null` or it equals to `all.Market`.

Comment: I am using coalesce like ISNULL function. http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-isnull/
If alarm.Buy =null then I want to replace all.market value

Comment: I know what it is and what it does. I am encouraging you not to use it in your LINQ, and instead think in terms of what I suggested.

Comment: You can do a cross join `from firstAll in Db.All from alarm in Db.Alarms` and just put the condition into a `where`.  Most modern DBs will be smart enough to create a query plan that will do a proper join.

Comment: I have tryed but with "from, from" synatax , left join is not working
@juharr

Comment: Here is code;

var allResult = from firstALL in Db.All
    from alarm in Db.Alarms.DefaultIfEmpty()
    .Where(x => (x.Buy ?? firstALL.Market) == firstALL.Market
      && (x.Parity ?? firstALL.Parity) == firstALL.Parity)
    select new
    {
     BUY = firstALL.Market,
     CPersentage = alarm.CPersentage
    };

Comment: Move the `DefaultIfEmpty` after the `Where`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it worked according to @juharr response.

Code is like,

```
 var allResult = from firstALL in Db.All
            from alarm in Db.Alarms
            .Where(x => (x.Buy ?? firstALL.Market) == firstALL.Market
                    && (x.Parity ?? firstALL.Parity) == firstALL.Parity).DefaultIfEmpty()
```